# list of base class pointers, get different return values for function member

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, idioms

**Imagine the following situation**

- You have a pointer to a variable: `fooVar *`
- You can get the type of the variable with a function like this: `get_type(fooVar* foo)` which is returning a int value `bar`
- You can then lookup in an `enum` to which type the returned value `bar` belongs, e.g. `1` -> `type_int`
- Depending on the type, you can then call one of the following functions to get the value: `double get_double(fooVar*)`, `int get_int(fooVar*)`, ...

**The goal is**

To wrap those functions (which is a simplified version of a C library) into a CPP class.

**The problem is**

- I would like to store a list of all Variables.
- How to return the current value of the variable in a uniform way?

I tried to create a BaseType and derive the other types from it, like that:

```
BaseClass
|--> IntClass - int getValue()
|--> DoubleClass - double getValue()
'--> BoolClass - bool getValue()
```

I could then create a member function `.getValue()` for each derived class with the correct return type (as shown above).
Since I am storing pointers to all Variables in a list of Type `BaseClass*`, my compiler is now complaining that `getValue()` is not defined when I am trying to call it.

A second solution might be to create `double getAsDouble()`, `bool getAsBool()`, `int getAsInt()` and then throw an error if the type is not convertible or if it doesn't fit. But that feels wrong, too.

A third solution might be to not only store the pointer but also the type it points to (of the derived class). Later on I could then cast the BasePointer. But it it really a good idea?

Another solution might involve `std::variant`, but I think that's overkill - right?

**The Question is:** How would you do that in C++? Is there a clean way to achieve that?

---

**Sidenote:** None of the topics I've read here on SO really fits, it feels like a standard problem to me so I would like to learn some ways professional programmers solve this kind of issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have gotten yourself into the corner of trying to re-implement virtual functions and dynamic inheritance.

So, perhaps the most straightforward thing you could do is have a `virtual BaseType::getValue()` function, which is overridden by the subclass-specific `getValue()`.

But these days, we try to avoid arrays of raw pointers - that requires explicit allocation and de-allocation, and is error prone (e.g. - what happens if you throw an exception?). At the very least, make it something like an `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseType>>` (or `std::shared_ptr` instead of `std::unique_ptr`). If you haven't heard about these pointer-like classes, read this:

[What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one/30143936)

Beyond that - if you know the set of possible types in advance, and its not huge - then, as you yourself suggested - an `std::variant` may be a reasonable choice. Variants in C++ are a bit unwieldy, but they're very safe; and one you get used to them, they're convenient enough. So, in your case:

```
using foo_var = std::variant<IntClass, DoubleClass, BoolClass>;

//...

auto foo_vars = get_array_of_foo_vars_somehow();

for(const foo_var& : foo_vars) {
    your_complex_visit([]auto&& arg) {
        using T = std::decay_t<decltype(arg)>;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
            std::cout << "int with value " << arg << '\n';
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
            std::cout << "double with value " << arg << '\n';
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, bool>)
            std::cout << "bool with value " << arg << '\n';
        else 
            static_assert(always_false_v<T>, "non-exhaustive visitor!");
    }, foo_var);
}

// Note: No need to `free()` anything when the array goes out of scope
```

Now, `your_complex_visit()` is a bit like `std::visit()`, except that you look at `arg.getValue()` intead of just `args()`. Or you *can* use `std::visit` in the above, but would need to change the types to the outer ones (`IntClass` instead of 'int' etc.)

Comment: Thank you so far! I will now try to understand and implement it. I will then come back to select the accepted answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: Could you maybe exand a little bit on "But these days, we try to avoid arrays of pointers." What would you prefer then, in general?

Comment: @ataraxis An array of objects, or at least an array of *smart* pointers (`unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`), not *raw* pointers

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Good point, I'll add that option.

Comment: @ataraxis: See edit regarding avoiding arrays of pointers.

Comment: @einpoklum: perfect, smart pointers is what i am using ;) I finally decided to return an std::variant<double, int, bool> from my getValue(). Guess that's the easiest way till I am more used to cpp.

Comment: @ataraxis: A fine choice, possibly also after you get used to C++. A variant is actually a very "simple" type - conceptually, even if not in its implementation - and choosing something simple is almost never a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

> A second solution might be to create `double getAsDouble()`, `bool getAsBool()`, `int getAsInt()` and then throw an error if the type is not convertible or if it doesn't fit. But that feels wrong, too.

A alteranative approach to throwing an exception in case of error could be to return `std::optional<double>`, `std::optional<bool>` and  `std::optional<int>` for `getAsDouble()`, `getAsBool()` and `getAsInt()`, respectively. This way, returning an empty `std::option` would then signal a failure – i.e., there is no such a value to retrieve – that isn't an error.

For example, if you had the following declarations corresponding to the C code:

```
struct FooVar;

int get_type(const FooVar*);

int get_int(const FooVar*);
double get_double(const FooVar*);

#define INT_TYPE    1 
#define DOUBLE_TYPE 2
```

You could write a wrapper class that contains user-defined conversion operators to `FooVar *` and `const FooVar *`:

```
class FooVarWrapper {
   FooVar *ptr_;
public:
   // ...

   operator FooVar*() noexcept { return ptr_; }
   operator const FooVar*() const noexcept { return ptr_; }

   // ...
};
```

Note that thanks to the conversion operators, you can still use the C API directly with this wrapper class, e.g., you can call your original function `get_type()` with a `FooVarWrapper` object as an argument because this will be implicitly converted into the stored `FooVar *`.

Then, you can define those getter functions as *non-member* functions as well:

```
std::optional<int> getAsInt(const FooVarWrapper& obj) {
   if (INT_TYPE != get_type(obj))
      return std::nullopt;

   return get_int(obj);
}

std::optional<double> getAsDouble(const FooVarWrapper& obj) {
   if (DOUBLE_TYPE != get_type(obj))
      return std::nullopt;
   
   return get_double(obj);
}

// ... similarly for getAsBool()
```

However, you may want to consider marking the conversions operators as `explicit` to avoid easily bypassing these functions that return `std::optional` by calling `get_int()` or `get_double()` directly. This way, you will need to write `static_cast<>` whenever you want to convert a `FooVarWrapper` object into the stored pointer; the conversion won't occur implicitly.

Comment: that's complex, let me see if I understand it after a while xD thank you anyway!